# Convert vertical data to panel data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this which has ids and different dates and amount.

```
id  date    amount
1   2023-01-01  20
1   2023-01-02  0
1   2023-01-03  0
1   2023-01-04  10
1   2023-01-05  15
1   2023-01-06  0
1   2023-01-07  0
2   2023-02-13  25
2   2023-02-14  32
2   2023-02-15  0
2   2023-02-16  12
2   2023-02-17  0
2   2023-02-18  0
2   2023-02-19  0
2   2023-02-20  13
2   2023-02-21  0
2   2023-02-22  12
```

I want to derive another dataset that looks like this that is horizontal panel data. In the dataset below, the t1..tn represent time, which can have maximum value of up to 5 years (1825 days - t1825). I have tried different approaches, but my mind is getting knotted up. How to do this? Thank you.

| id | date | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 | t7 | t8 | t9 | t10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 15 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-13 | 25 | 32 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | 2023-02-14 | 32 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-15 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-16 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-18 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-19 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-20 | 13 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-21 | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-22 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Update:
The panel data I want to generate is not scaling for large data (20M rows). The consecutive_zero_count column counts the consecutive 0 sales amount days. The last 3 columns is maximum number of consecutive_zero_count values between days 0 to 2, 3 to 5 and 6 to 9. The final data I want is below. Is there a better way to achieve this?

| id | date | amount | consec_zero_count | max_dnp_d0_d2 | max_dnp_d3_d5 | max_dnp_d6_d9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 20 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 15 | 0 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 | 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 | 0 | 2 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-13 | 25 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-02-14 | 32 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-15 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-16 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-02-17 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-18 | 0 | 4 | 5 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-19 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 0 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-20 | 13 | 0 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-21 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-22 | 12 | 0 | 0 | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["col"] = df.groupby("id").cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index=["id", "date"], columns="col", values="amount")

df = df.groupby("id", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.bfill().apply(
        lambda row: sorted(row, key=pd.isna), axis=1, result_type="expand"
    )
)
df.columns = "t" + (df.columns + 1).astype(str)

print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
    id        date    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    t7    t8    t9   t10
0    1  2023-01-01  20.0   0.0   0.0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    1  2023-01-02   0.0   0.0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1  2023-01-03   0.0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    1  2023-01-04  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    1  2023-01-05  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    1  2023-01-06   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6    1  2023-01-07   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
7    2  2023-02-13  25.0  32.0   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0
8    2  2023-02-14  32.0   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN
9    2  2023-02-15   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN
10   2  2023-02-16  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   2  2023-02-17   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   2  2023-02-18   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   2  2023-02-19   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
14   2  2023-02-20  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
15   2  2023-02-21   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
16   2  2023-02-22  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.shift.html):

```
g = df.groupby('id')['amount']

out = df.join(pd.concat({f't{x+1}': g.shift(-x)
                         for x in range(1, g.size().max())},
                        axis=1)
              ).rename(columns={'amount': 't1'})
```

Or numpy's [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), which should be more efficient:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

def to_panel(g):
    return pd.DataFrame(swv(np.pad(g.astype(float),
                                   (0, len(g)-1), 
                                   constant_values=np.nan),
                            len(g)), 
                        index=g.index)

out = df.join(df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['amount']
                .apply(to_panel)
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f't{x+1}')
              ).drop(columns='amount')
```

Output:

```
    id        date  t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    t7    t8    t9   t10
0    1  2023-01-01  20   0.0   0.0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    1  2023-01-02   0   0.0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1  2023-01-03   0  10.0  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    1  2023-01-04  10  15.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    1  2023-01-05  15   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    1  2023-01-06   0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6    1  2023-01-07   0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
7    2  2023-02-13  25  32.0   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0
8    2  2023-02-14  32   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN
9    2  2023-02-15   0  12.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN
10   2  2023-02-16  12   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   2  2023-02-17   0   0.0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   2  2023-02-18   0   0.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   2  2023-02-19   0  13.0   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
14   2  2023-02-20  13   0.0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
15   2  2023-02-21   0  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
16   2  2023-02-22  12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing both solutions.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be interested to have the timings on your real dataset

Comment: I have a dataset with 20 millon rows and it is not scaling on that data. I think the panel approach I want to do doesn't scale.

Comment: 20m rows * 2k columns (=20b cells!) is quite big for pandas.

Comment: That is right. I didn't realized that before. I have updated my question above to include the final data I am looking for. Is there a more efficient way to get there?